# Angular template context changes the property which holds it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a view component, that takes in a list of options (an option has a template, a label, and a templatecontext) and based on that, it renders a list of labels in which a user can select an option, and also renders the option's template with the template context supplied in an ng-container. It is working fine when using different templates, however when using the same template but with a different context, after selecting an other option, the last options context changes in the @Input list parameter.

My Option class is as follows:

```
export class Option {
  template: TemplateRef<any> | null
  label: string
  context: any

  constructor(template: TemplateRef<any> | null, label: string, context: any) {
    this.template = template;
    this.label = label;
    this.context = context
  }
}
```

The view component has the following fields

```
@Input() options: Option[] = [] // this is the field that changes
selectindex = 0;       // this holds the currently selected option to render
```

On the view components template this is how I render the template:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="options[selectindex].template || default" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="options[selectindex].context"></ng-container>
```

This is the list on the parent component, that I supply to the view component

```
 this.options = [
            new Option(this.loading, 'Balance', {amount: 'Data1'}),
            new Option(this.table, 'Income', {amount: 'Data2'}),
            new Option(this.table, 'Expense', {amount: 'Data3'}),
          ]
```

After loading the page everything is fine: [image: after load]

Console logging options from the view component in this state shows the right data.

After I select any other option, such as expense, it works:

[image: after selecting expense]

However, if I  console.log now, I can see the context of Balance changed, from 'Data1' to the context of the selected option, Expense, 'Data3'. If I now switch back to Balance, I can see it doesn't work:
[image: When it is not working]

What is happening? Nothing ever writes to the option list, it is only accessed from the html, using ngtemplatecontext. The only thing that happens on selecting an option is as follows: selectindex = i.

EDIT: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fljgeo?file=src/app/hello.component.ts here is a minimal reproduction of the problem on stackblitz

Comment: Nothing in your current code changes that reference, so it's something else that you haven't posted. Not sure anyone will be able to help you at this one if you don't provide some minimal repro on stackblitz or other service.

Comment: Working on the minimal reproduction, the problem is, that really nothing changes the reference, if I delete the line that renders my template with the context, and try the code, it works and options does not change.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, for me its working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xv9mqa-tplcontext?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In your implementation, you used different templates for different options, that is working fine for me also, what is not working, is when I use the same template just with different contexts

Comment: gotcha, but i can work around this with copying the context on each selection https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xv9mqa-tplcontext-2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fljgeo?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Reproduced my issue, it is the most minimal I could create

Comment: Gonna use your workaround if I cannot solve this issue of mine

Comment: It seems like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so solved it, could not find out how  can the bug occur, or what is the cause, most likely it is a bug in angular framework. Yet managed to do an easy workaround, instead of switching the components in ng-template-outlet, I render all of them with an ngfor, and render only the selected one for real with gif, as follows:

```
       <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options; index as i;">
          <ng-container *ngIf="selectindex === i">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="option.template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="option.context"></ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: But this unfortunately doesn't work if you want to render contents of the template in each ngFor